# What is the best way to keep track on tables or some data for analytics?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, analytics

For an instance, take `django` model classes as below.

So, now the question is that how can I efficiently implement analytics for generating **number of product sales per day, number of sales per month, number of profit by day and so on** ?

One Possible solution is on every sales update counts of that particular day. But if I have very large customer base (i.e 1M customer and 500 sales per hour).

So is there any better way to achieve this?

*These schemas are just for reference only*

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.ManyToManyField("Category", null=True)
    ...
    ...


class Sales(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: where and how often do you want to access these statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Model `SalesStatistics` which store the count of sales every predefined interval. If hourly, daily and monthly statistics are required, storing hourly statistic should suffice.

There are two ways simple of achieving this -

1. Write a cron job that runs every hour, calculate the number of sales in an hour.

```
id,   sales_count, timestamp
__________________________________
1231  304          "2 pm, 21st April 2019"
1232  443          "3 pm, 21st April 2019"
```

You can retreive hourly, daily or monthly easily from this using any RDBMS

> MYSQL offers a vast number of date time function to making querying time series data easy. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

2. Use a builtin `event schedulers` in databases. In databases, you can schedule to run a query at some time intervals and the store the result in a table. `[MySQL Event Scheduler][1]`

Answer (score 1):

this is usually done by service like google analytics.

You can find the doc here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009612